# Can't get local ip4 address only server address

Tags: c#, iis, network-programming

Hi I'm trying to get my local ip4 address but the result only returning the IP of the IIS Server

here's my code:

```
        public string GetLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType _type)
    {
        string output = "";
        foreach (NetworkInterface item in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (item.NetworkInterfaceType == _type && item.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in item.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        output = ip.Address.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

 string IPAddress = GetLocalIPv4(NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet);
```

The IIS Authentication is I only enable the windows authentication, because I'm using window authentication. But why the returning ip is not my local ip4 instead the IIS server address?

Comment: What is should return ? And what is is returning? Can you add some sample expected and actual data?

Comment: it should return my local ip address not my web server

Answer (score 0):

In general:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Tedious approach:

```
    using System.Net.Sockets;

    foreach(IPAddress ip in Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Environment.MachineName.AddressList){
        if(ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            Console.WriteLine("IPV4"+ip.ToString());
        if(ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
            Console.WriteLine("IPV6"+ip.ToString());
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.addressfamily(v=vs.110).aspx